# LeakCanary - D/LeakCanary: Could not attempt cleanup, leak storage not writable

Tags: android, android-memory, leakcanary

I added LeakCanary in My Application. Here is my Application Class

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application{

    private RefWatcher refWatcher;
    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.w("Trendy", "LeakCanary Installation");
        refWatcher = LeakCanary.install(this);
    }

    public static RefWatcher getRefWatcher(Context context) {
        GlobalClass application = (GlobalClass) context.getApplicationContext();
        return application.refWatcher;
    }
}
```

But at startup it says

> D/LeakCanary: Could not attempt cleanup, leak storage not writable.

I have already give External Read/Write rights to my application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: If you're on Android 6+ you have to request the permission: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/permissions

Comment: @Exaqt Which permission, I have already requested permission for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Did you request the permission on runtime? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351236/stuck-at-dumping-memory-app-will-freeze-brrr-message

Comment: @Alex did u fix this issue?

Comment: if any one still having same issue check this link https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/489